# Optional URL end in RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the digits from a url with an optional ending

```
/^\/course\/(\d+)\/view/
```

The `/view` part is optional.

I've tried various combinations of (..)? around it but can't get it to work.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: @blex works perfect please can you make it an anwser

Comment: neither of those answers helped answer my question. @blex had a much better answer - /^\/course\/(\d+)(?=(\/view)?)/, which worked perfectly. While the question is generic, the answer is specific and should remain.